# Renaming an SQL database in android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

When referring to database tables I usually use syntax like this: `my_database_name.my_table_name`

I am trying to do the same in Android but am having trouble understanding how to name a database.

Would you just execute this SQL as you would in the Sqlite3 client? i.e.

```
ATTACH "my_database_file" AS my_database_name;
```

Here is what I tried in my onCreate method:

```
db.execSQL("Attach 'hq_db' AS hq_db;");
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
04-05 11:13:35.676: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(860): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: cannot ATTACH database within transaction: Attach 'hq_db' AS hq_db;
```

How do I execute SQL statements on Android outside of a transaction to make this work?

Edit: It might also have something to so with the superclass constuctor, though the super class constructor string sets the file name (which is working properly) and it seems nothing else:

```
private class databaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public q_player_databaseOpenHelper() {
            super(MyApp.getContext(), "my_db_file", null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL("Attach 'my_db_file' AS my_db_name;");
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");

        }
```

Note: I have stripped this code down so it would fit my problem

Comment: As I remember there is only one database created for your application. So you don't have to access tables through a database name.

Comment: Vladimir, you are right, but I may need to add databases in the future (or have two versions of the same database which will have different database names but the same table names) so naming can be used to avoid conflicts

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `db.execSQL("ATTACH 'hq_db' AS hq_db;");` before you start any kind of transaction. Do the attachment first, and then start the transaction.

Are you calling `beginTransaction` or executing SQL which begins a transaction before trying to attach your other database?

Comment: Neither, This is the first SQL statement I am attempting to execute and it is failing so no other SQL is being run (at least not by me explicitly)

Comment: In your onCreate you are attaching the database to itself by calling `db.execSQL("Attach 'my_db_file' AS my_db_name;");`. All this is doing is letting you access the database through two names - `my_db_file` and `my_db_name`. There is a limit to the number of databases that can be attached to one-another in SQLite - my guess is on Android this is 1. Remove your initial attachment in your onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably creating the database with AutoCommit=0.  This puts you in a transaction so that it doesn't need to write to the database file after every INSERT.  But it also means you can't ATTACH to another database.  Create the DB, set AutoCommit=1, ATTACH, then set AutoCommit=0.